# Making Ubuntu a minimal NAT?

Tags: ubuntu, nat

I need to make a quick-and-dirty NAT out of a Ubuntu 10.10 box. Just "this side is NATted with DHCP handing out 192.168.x.0/24" and "this side gateways to the Internet", and nothing else interesting. There seems to be many choices with varying degrees of documentation. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.d/10-network-security.conf
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o externaleth -j SNAT --to externalip
apt-get install dhcp3-server
gedit /etc/default/dhcp3-server
interfaces="internaleth1" #eth2 or eth3 or whatyouhave :D
gedit /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option routers                  192.168.0.1; #yours itnernal ip
    option subnet-mask              255.255.255.0;

    option domain-name              "mylan.com";
    option domain-name-servers       192.168.0.1;
    range 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.254;
}

apt-get install dns-masq
service dhcp3-server restart
```

1. setting nat
2. install dhcpd-server
3. install dnsmasq to handle option domain-name-servers       192.168.0.1; or you could set it to 8.8.8.8 and skip install dns-masq

Comment: dnsmasq also does DHCP. If you're going to install dnsmasq, I wouldn't don't bother with dhcp3-server.

Comment: ive got some problems with vpn-s and dhcpd dnsmasq. and i dont know why that worked for me. now im having my own bind9 for that :D

Comment: The iptables part of this answer works fine. There is, I think, at least one bug in the dhcpd stuff, namely that the interface in /etc/default/dhcp3-server should be the *internal* interface (where systems send their DHCP requests", not the external one.

Comment: @Paul Hoffman you are right.

Comment: And a late comment because this came and bit me on the butt late in the game: do not forget to "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" every time you boot this box.

Comment: oh,echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.d/10-network-security.conf

this will fix that.

Comment: I haven't been using ubuntu lately, but I suppose you should install `iptables-persistent` and/or do some additional steps to make the nat rule persistent over reboots, right?

Comment: ive make a sctipt for that, 'cos ive have a lot of conditions for iptables rules, and put it in rc.local. but you can alse use iptables-save iptables-restore via if-up if-down scripts for interface.

Answer (score 1):

I in fact do exactly this -- for a couple of years an old HP mini-tower served as my home network's router, until it fried in a blackout (hardware's not worth troubleshooting the fault); I'll be building a brand new system for this very same purpose shortly, so I'll be sure to write up a how-to as I do that.

In the meantime, however, I'll point you to the same resource I use: [Shorewall](http://www.shorewall.net/), and specifically the how-to for a [two-interface firewall](http://www.shorewall.net/two-interface.htm). The site's documentation also has similar articles for one- and three-interface setups, so pick the one that best suits your needs. I find using Shorewall to be a lot easier and a lot more intuitive than directly manipulating iptables (Shorewall is really just a configuration layer that sits atop iptables, so the end result is very much the same, except that it handles a lot of basic, low-level stuff you wouldn't even think of, like smurfs (packets with a broadcast address as the source) and martians (packets with impossible source addresses)).